# Signing a code and application

Tags: digital-signature, code-signing

I want to send my application to different servers/terminals with content integrity and confidentiality.
So, I need to some process to sign my code and application before sending it to servers and to ensure that the software comes from a trusted source and has not been altered.
What do you suggest? What are the most common practices?

For example, use a symmetric key to encrypt the code and a public key to protect the symmetric key and hash of package?

Answer (score 2):

That is the basic idea, but you probably don't want to implement a custom solution. Depending on your operating system there is probably already a mechanism, for example Debian's **SecureApt** which leverages GPG.

https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt